# Avoiding duplication of code in a "receive" when an input changes the type of messages being received

Tags: erlang

I want to be able to write a function which when its input is in some invalid state (let's say it's an integer, and invalid means -1), it receives messages with any kind of information, but when its input is valid, it only receives messages of the same kind as its input. As an example, this is what a possible solution might look like:

```
f(-1) ->
    receive
        ...
        {a, AnyInput} ->
            % Do something
        ...
    end

f(ValidInput) ->
    receive
        ...
        {a, ValidInput} ->
            % Do something
        ...
    end
```

The main concern here is duplicating code, as the receive contains a large amount of, otherwise, identical code (there are also many other messages types in the same receive).

Is there any coding pattern which could help me here?

I also have the freedom to set the invalid state as any value, including undef, if that would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f(Input) ->
    receive
        ...
        {a, AnyInput} when Input =:= -1 ->
            % Do something
        ...
        {a, Input} ->
            % Do something
        ...
    end
```